# jQuery selector with injected PHP variable returns nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm experiencing the weirdest problem I've ever met. This has worked a thousand times before, but now I simply hit a wall on this seemingly impossible-to-solve problem.

I have a custom data-attribute on an element:

```
<a href="#" data-pbid="5">My anchor</a>
```

I'm targeting this and alerting the amount of elements found:

```
var myAnchor = $("a[data-pbid=5]");
alert(myAnchor.length) //Alerts "1".
```

**However, when I change this to an injected PHP variable, it just doesnt work:**
(Im mixing a bit of code together here, but you know what's what.)

```
var_dump($pbid); //returns string(1):"5"

<a href="#" data-pbid="<?php echo $pbid?>">My anchor</a>

var myAnchor = $("a[data-pbid=<?php echo $pbid?>]");
alert(myAnchor.length) //Alerts "0".
```

What on earth is going on here?

**Thanks in advance,**

Rasmus Dencker

Comment: What does the anchor look like in the HTML source?

Comment: Never try to debug client side code by looking at server side code. Run the server side code. Debug the client side code. Work out what changes the client side code needs. Then worry about how to make the server side code output the right client side code.

Comment: Actually I'm working in Laravel. $pbid is passed through to the View. If I however set the $pbid manually in the view, it works. What's weird is that `var_dump($pbid); $pbid=5; var_dump($pbid);` returns exactly the same, but the jQuery selector only works when it's set explicitly within the view.

Comment: @Quentin I am aware that this is bad practice, but this case is so amazingly simple that it (in this case) really, in my world, is OK to do it like this.

Comment: @Dencker — Your previous comment suggests that the problem is "The PHP variable is not set". There is no way to tell that from the description of the problem or the code you shared with us. It would have been obvious if you had looked at the generated code. So no, it isn't OK, you wasted your time and ours.

Comment: @Quentin I'm showing you a var_dump, which suggests that the variable is indeed set. That's the server side part.

Comment: Have you tried viewing your HTML source? Is '5' actually echoed into the source?

Comment: @Jonathon Yep - it is.

Comment: Could it potentially be a case of missing semi-colons on your echo statements? Not sure how strict PHP is on this...

Comment: Is it being echoed both into the script and the anchor?

Comment: @Jonathon - Tried explicitly putting the semicolons. Still no dice unfortunately. And yes indeed, they're echoed in both the script and the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this. In the OP I forgot to mention the fact that the elements were loaded and injected through ajax, and without explicitly setting the variable I somehow had a bit of a lag between the generation and the execution of the code. As a temporary hack I just put in a

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
                    //the stuff that had to be done
                     }, 500);
```

Thanks for your willingness to help!

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of a missing semicolon or the lack of the space between your variable and PHP end tag.
Change this

`<a href="#" data-pbid="<?php echo $pbid?>">My anchor</a>`
to
`<a href="#" data-pbid="<?php echo $pbid; ?>">My anchor</a>`

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer - If I check the source, however, the variables are echoed correctly into both the script and the anchor.

Comment: It does? How about you store the PHP variable in a javascript variable and pass it in the jQuery selector, like this:
`var pbid = "<?php echo $pbid; ?>";
 var myAnchor = $("a[data-pbid='"+pbid+"']");`

Comment: i think the last semicolon is optional in PHP.

Comment: When you're writing a one-line statement, yeah. But the spaces are very much important.

Comment: @BasitSaeed, tried assigning it to a JS Variable. It gets assigned properly (alerting the variable), but no dice on the .length..

Comment: Strange! Can you create a jsFiddle and post its link in the original question for us to play with?

Comment: @BasitSaeed, thanks for your helpfulness. See my own answer - found a solution.